# Phing: get a filename without the extension

Tags: phing

Given a Phing loop such as this

```
<target name="lessc">
  <exec command="lessc ${absolute-filename}" logoutput="false" output="${project.basedir}/public/assets/css/libraries/${filename}" />
</target>

<target name="build-in-loop">
  <foreach param="filename" absparam="absolute-filename" target="lessc">
    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/assets/less/libraries/">
      <include name="*.less"/>
    </fileset>
  </foreach>
</target>
```

In target lessc, how can I extract the file name without extension from the variable `absolute-filename`? In the example above, the `output` file will have the extension `.less` - obviously not what I need.

I know there is a task made for less, and that I could extend Phing to support this specific operation, but I would like to know first if Phing basically allows simple string manipulation on variables.

Comment: Where is the mapper part in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, not sure if it's the best solution, but works for me:

just need to use the mapper tag

```
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.less" to="*"/>
```

in the `foreach` loop, like this:

```
<target name="build-in-loop">
  <foreach param="filename" absparam="absolute-filename" target="lessc">
    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/assets/less/libraries/">
      <include name="*.less"/>
    </fileset>
  </foreach>
</target>
```

At this point, in the variable `${filename}` in the `target` task there will be the filename without extension.